# $var = $input || 'default' in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry if the title isn't clear enough, but in Javascript you can do this :

```
var input = null;
var fruit = input || 'default';
```

Just wondering if PHP supports that kind of checking, currently I'm using :

$fruit = !empty($input)?$input : 'default' ;

Which is quite good, but of course the Javascript method is more elegant.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` returns a boolean in PHP, so this operator cannot be used for it. Same for `or`.

However, you can use the *binary* `?:` operator if you are using PHP5.3+:

```
$fruit = $input ?: 'default';
```

However, it has one great disadvantage destroying its usefulness in the single case where it would be most useful (when importing request variables):

```
$fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'] ?: 'strawberry';
```

This would throw an `E_NOTICE` in your face if `$_REQUEST['fruit']` didn't exist. So in this case you still need the *ternary* version of it with an `isset` or `!empty` check.

Comment: @deceze: Nobody should be using an older version anymore. downvoter: Please explain.

Comment: in addition to what ThiefMaster said, you could do a !!$input ?: 'default', haven't tried but might get you ridd of the E_NOTICE

Comment: I highly doubt that. You still read a variable that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the `||` operator returns a boolean, thus you will always get either true or false from it.  The reason it's possible in JS is because it will return a value.

So, no, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't because it returns a Boolean, not the last evaluated expression like in JavaScript or Ruby.

You can use a ternary or the new binary form that [ThiefMaster mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11045917/31671).